# Images in cards

Tags: material-design-lite

Why are the images for the cards component being used as a background instead of the image to fill up the media portion of the card? cant we just use the image tag instead?

I am trying to use the MDL framework to make a tumblr template
but having trouble implementing the card component for the images posts since tumblr uses image tags

please explain why MDL is using images as backgrounds for the card component

Comment: The examples provided simply use background image. You are free to insert a standard img tag all you want, along with any other media tag. There is no hard-rule as to the media being added via CSS. This is done in the examples since the media is not a primary piece of the cards, but a stylistic enhancement.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is really holding you back from using the `img` tag. See [this](http://codepen.io/yan-foto/pen/GJGpYb) as an example.

However using images as background of `div`s has some advantages:

1. Right clicking on the image does not allow you to download the image
2. You have more flexibility in terms of responsiveness (e.g. by using `background-size: cover` to fill the `div`). **UPDATE:** even though you can set 100% on width/height to adapt the image, `cover` keeps the aspect ratio and in general provides better results.
3. Since your image is just a background you don't need to set its position to `absolute` to let other elements inside the `div` be positioned over the image (as it is the case in all of MDL examples)

Comment: yeah but tumblr does not work that way, I would have to somehow make a dynamic card class for each image post be used, that seems complicated

Comment: Are you creating a new tumblr theme? I don't seem to understand the problem. Did you see the code example I sent?

Comment: You can width/height 100% the media within the media element to get them to be mostly responsive. So point 2 is entirely achievable without a CSS image solution. We don't do this by default, since it could change the ratio of images people put in there and that isn't nice.